# sqlalchemy ORM : how to give some low-level specification?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using ORM in [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org). The actual situation is I'm also using MySQL database, and I want to set some [table configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#storage-engines) that MySQL has to fit my project.(eg. `mysql_engine='InnoDB'`, `mysql_charset='utf8'` and so on)

I know there's an approach using the SQL Expression provided by SA. But i prefer to use ORM interface instead. Any ideas?

**P.S: How to make the same effect using 'class mytable' form (using ORM instead of SQL Expression maker)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can pass mysql options in your Table definition in sqlalchemy.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/mysql.html#storage-engines

```
Table('mytable', metadata,
  Column('data', String(32)),
  mysql_engine='InnoDB',
  mysql_charset='utf8'
 )
```

edit://

if you use the declarative layer, you can use '**table_args**' :

```
class Something(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'something'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_charset': 'utf8', 'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}
```

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/declarative.html#table-configuration

Comment: I know this method. The question is how to make the same effect using 'class mytable' form (using ORM instead of SQL Expression maker).